# Sorting a PMD report's contents by severity/priority in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

Is it possible to generate a PMD report in Eclipse whose contents are sorted by severity/priority? I.e. the most severe findings are listed first and then less severe than these etc.?

EDIT: We can generate reports in xml (which contains 'priority' field) and sort them but I'm wondering if there's an out-of-the-box option/tool for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have in PMD available [CSV](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_userdocs_getting_started.html#available-report-formats--renderers) format which you can open in Excel and sort by priority which is available by default

> priority: Include priority column. Default: true.

Comment: I used `pmd check -d C:\src\ -f sarif  -R category/apex/bestpractices.xml -r C:\src\PMD_Report_all_categories_sarif` I got priority 1 for code style and 3 for a security finding or a error prone finding. I expected the other way around: 1 for security findings. 
Do you know which priorty value is high and which is low?